# Error in $A.getCallback() [updatemethod is not defined] Callback failed: apex://comApexcontroler/ACTION$updatemethod Failing descriptor:

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am calling an Apex function from helper but it is throwing the below error

**`This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in $A.getCallback() [updatemethod is not defined] Callback failed: apex://comApexcontroler/ACTION$updatemethod Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AccComponent}`**

The below code is just part of the code. In console I am getting pid and aID.

**Apex Controller :**

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public Static String updatemethod(String pid, String aID){
            String message;

         List<Opportunity> oplist= new List<Opportunity>();
        oplist= [Select Id,Name,lookup__c from Opportunity where id=:pid limit 1];

        for(Opportunity opp: oplist){
            opp.lookup__c = aID;
            oplist.add(opp);
            message= 'Success';
          }

        update oplist;
        return 'Success';
    }
```

**Component Helper :**

```
 fun1: function(component, event, aID){
       var url= component.get("v.url");  
       var pid= component.get("v.pid");
       var action = component.get('c.updatemethod'); 
         action.setParams({ "pid" : pid,
                                 "aID": aID
                        }); 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
          var state = response.getState();
           console.log('******Valid And State'+'ss'+state); // Here the state is showing as ERROR

          if(state==="SUCCESS"){
              console.log("Entered if" );

                     updatemethod(pid,aID);
                     window.location.href= url;              



          }         
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);  
    },
```

Comment: Also, I'd be remiss if I didn't point out this code is terrible. If you know any one that could give you a code review and explain the whys and hows, I would suggest you do so. There is a lot to be learned; that method could be 1 line. If you don't have anyone, I can put something together and post to gist or something.

Comment: @wellmstein Thanks for your response. I am new to Lightning I will learn in the process :) It will be helpful if you can pointout the mistakes

Comment: here is some basic comments, hope they help. Good luck, keep learning! https://gist.github.com/maxwellmstein/d096e41838b931d4c7bb4c6793398b9e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside of your callback you have this

```
updatemethod(pid,aID);
```

That method is not defined in your javascript. Not sure what you want to happen on success, either define that method on the helper and call helper.updatemethod or remove it. Just as warning be careful not to name your APEX methods the same name as your lightning-controller methods.